# changing the position of listview items to right

Tags: android, listview

I have been working with listviews and arrays, what I am struggling with is that I want the items of the listview to be on the right instead of left and the scroll bar on left
here's my xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="36dp"
        android:background="#00688B"
        android:cacheColorHint="#fff"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="false"
        android:smoothScrollbar="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

java

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        String[] captionArray = { "USA","India","England","Russia","Europe","Canada","Srilanka","Singapore","Thailand","Australia"};
        ItemsAdapter ItemsAdapter = new ItemsAdapter(
                Lister.this, R.layout.list,
                captionArray);
        setListAdapter(ItemsAdapter);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Giving you a Link where you will have to make some changes. [LINK](http://willvk.blogspot.in/2011/07/adding-arrow-image-to-right-of-listview.html)

In main.xml you can remove the ImageView and set Following Tag to TextView

```
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

Other Things are in that site only.

Hope this Helps you.